# I need help to create a python program that can calculate GPA

Tags: python, calculator

Create a python program that requires the GPA of 5 classes. It has to be: 2-3 credits 89 and 70, 2-2 credits 94 and 80, 1-4 credits 95. 
I came up with this but have not gotten far.:

```
   def name():
    name = input ("Enter a student name ")
    Grade1 = input ("Enter a grade: ")
    Grade2= input ("Enter a grade: ")
    Grade3 = input ("Enter a grade: ")
    Grade4 = input ("Enter a grade: ")
    Grade5 = input ("Enter a grade: ")
    return name, Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5

def Grades(Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5):
        if (Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5) == '2 credits' or (Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5) == '3 credits'
            (G1, G2, G3, G4, G5)= 89 and 90
        elif (Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5) == '2 credits' or (Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5)=='2 credits'
            (G1, G2, G3, G4, G5)= 94 and 80
        elif (Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5)== '1 credit' or (Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5)== '4 credits'
            (G1, G2, G3, G4, G5)= 95
        else:
            return 'invalid grade'
        return G1,G2,G3,G4,G5

def GPA(G1,G2,G3,G4,G5):
    GPA = (G1,G2,G3,G4,G5)/5
    return GPA
def main(name, GPA):
    print "The GPA for", name, "is", GPA
    return 0

Name()=name,Grade1,Grade2,Grade3,Grade4,Grade5
Grades(Grade1,Grade2,Grade3,Grade4,Grade5)=G1,G2,G3,G4,G5
GPA(G1,G2,G3,G4,G5)=GPA
main(name,GPA)=0
```

Comment: this needs a lot of work

Comment: you're comparing a tuple to a string thats not going to work. Moreover there are a series of bugs in your code. like the assignment of a tuple to a boolean (using and) and so many wrong logic threads i cant even explain all of them

Comment: best advice i can give is read your textbook and other python intro texts and do some tutorials.. this code is beyond salvageable.... at this point, if anyone on this site wrote the program for you it, it would be doing you a disservice

Comment: Then there's the fact that at the bottom you are assigning functions tuple values. That just doesn't make sense.
edit: Actually, at the bottom your assignment is just backwards flip them